# On Nucleus-Nucleus potential for fusion reaction of light nuclei

Tags: nuclear-physics, interactions, fusion

Its know that in nuclear fusion reactions, the nucleus-nucleus potential cannot be simply given by;

$V(r)=\frac{kZ_pZ_t}{r} for, r>\frac{kZ_pZ_t}{E}$

$V(r)=-U_0 , or,  \frac{-U_0}{1+e^{\frac{a-r}{b}}} for, r<\frac{kZ_pZ_t}{E}$

Where E is the incident energy of the projectile and term $\frac{-U_0}{1+e^{\frac{a-r}{b}}}$ is Woods-Saxon potential with parameters $a$ and $b$. $k$ is the electrostatic constant. Since that there are other many factors that affect the effective nucleus-nucleus potential. I’m searched too long for an expermintal-based nucleus-nucleus potential but I only found the Bass potential for heavy nuclei fusion reactions [[1]](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-09965-4_23). But I never found any for light nuclei fusion. I’m looking specifically for the nucleus-nucleus potential for deuterium-tritium fusion reactions. Can any one here please give me some references of articles describing such interaction on experimental basis? And if its possible I would like to know about all experimentally driven nucleus-nucleus potentials found until this time.
Thank you.